# Add a hyperlink within Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, svg

Is it possible to add a hyperlink to an object or a layer within Illustrator CS6 for a later SVG export?

I know about the possibility to manually edit the exported file and wrap elements with an `<a>` tag. But this complicates subsequent changes. It would be better to have solution that is integrated in Illustrator.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's possible.

- Select your object
- Call "Attributes panel" <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>
- In dropdown "Image input" select "Polygon"
- Paste your link in input "URL"
- Save as SVG
- Check in browser
- Profit

[image]

Comment: I feel like the last step is the most overlooked :)

Comment: CC2018 Export to SVG. XML doesn't contain anything about the hyperlinks I created on some rectangles

Comment: @dstonek, I had the same issue when I used 'Export As'. However, when you use 'Save As', the links work. I just edited the instruction in this Answer.

Comment: @sergeydyadyul Mouse over the polygon, the browser displays the correct url to follow but console displays an error. Link is not followed. I remember I had similar problems 2 years ago and finally I decided to use jpgs. I'll make  a new question

Comment: In Firefox one of the links is followed but opened inside the image div box. Don't know how to add source="_blank", Trying to follow the other link I get a Mixed Content error which doesn't make sense. It says "...was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://..." which is not true at least from my side.  Bye bye svg with hyperlinks. Let's see what will happen in 2022. I'm using CC2019

Comment: Note, in CS6, you need to enable "Web" in order to see the URL field. E.g., in the top bar, where it says "Essentials", select "Web". Otherwise, only "Overprint Fill" is shown.

Comment: I show this is a video: https://youtu.be/PX14QgWHoYA