# Illustrator exported svg does not contain defined hyperlinks

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

CC2018 22.1
According to [Add a hyperlink within Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27497/add-a-hyperlink-within-illustrator)  I followed those steps but I cannot get hyperlinks work in browsers.
I have a complex Illustrator design (several paths) I've added 4 rectangles for a link map.
[image]
Here it is the Attributes of one of those rectangles and the SVG Options during export.
I unchecked "Minify" to get a more readable output.
Reading the preview by clicking "Show Code" or reading the final .svg file there's no sign of anchor hrefs.
At bottom 4 like this `<rect class="cls-5" x="76.5" width="886.82" height="327.54"/>`
`cls-5` -> `fill:none`

I tried to manually add the anchors like
 `<a xlink:href="index.php"><rect class="cls-5" x="76.5" width="886.82" height="327.54"/></a>`
and also the xlink reference
`<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" .....`

It didn't work as advertised here: https://alligator.io/svg/hyperlinks-svg/
    It only does when the code is inline the html file, not using it inside `myfile.svg` like
`<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 500px)" srcset="images/myfile.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
............

</picture>`

1) I want to solve this from Illustrator.
2) If not possible I want to know how to add those hyperlinks manually in the .svg file, if possible.

[image]

Comment: You can make the other objects not participate in selections see [pointer-events](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty), also object can be invisible and participate

Comment: That's okay, I added `pointer-events: visible;` to fix link visibility but only  inline, the svg expanded in the body of the html script. I don't know how to make the link areas visible if svg tag is included in .svg file `<img src="images/test3.svg" type="image/svg+xml">`despite `fill` or `pointer-events`values

Comment: That's not specifically about graphic design so I guess I'd start another question in the appropriate discusion site

Comment: And why AI let us include hyperlinks if after all they are not included in the svg file?

Comment: Its included theres just no trigger, AI is not responsible for the behavior of each browser in the universe. Each browser is allowed to do what it wants.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to see your code.

Here a link to my SVG with hyperlinks: https://danielillo.neocities.org/

I just added manually the cursor style = pointer

```
<a xlink:href="https://www.google.com" cursor="pointer">
<polygon id="XMLID_1_" fill="#E0DE16" points="58.9,136 0,102 0,34 0,34 58.9,68  "/>
</a>
```

I guess the problem is the link type: index.php

Comment: I saw your example. You didn't understand my question. Yours is an inline script. I am asking for the content of myfile.svg I use in a <picture> tag

Comment: Did you read this at your link page: –This only works with inline SVGs, not with SVGs that are included in an <img> tag.–

Comment: Of course, that's what I've state in my question.

Answer (score 0):

For any future readers, if you use Save as SVG instead of Export As, the links set up in the Attributes panel should work in browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, defined hyperlinks do not work in exported SVGs from AI. Can't find any workaround. Adobe, do something about it.

Comment: Please only use the "answer" space for actual answers, do not post rants or support requests. Check [answer] to learn more.